# Can Azure Cognitive Search Index Use A Lookup Table?

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have created an Azure Cognitive Search Service index. All the fields that I want to be able to search, retrieve, filter, sort, facet  are included within the single table that the index is built from. Some of the data fields in that table are coded, but I have a separate table that serves as a dictionary that defines those codes more literally in plain english. I would like to be able to search on the defined/literal values in my search results from the index without having to add the contents of the large dictionary table to the search index.

Is it possible to configure the index to use a referential table in this way? How?

Or is my only option to denormalize the entire contents of the dictionary into the index table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cognitive Search Services will only return data that it has stored in its search indexes. If you want to "join" that data with some external table, that's something you may need to do client-side.

If you want to search against the terms in your external table, that data needs to be included in the search index.

Comment: ok so this skill is not intended for joining a table? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-custom-entity-lookup